# Read first column in csv every time and change other columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that has over 300 columns and 5k rows. What I want to do is to read the first and the second columns in the first iteration, then read the first and the third columns in the second iteration, then read the first and  fourth columns in the third iteration and so on. Also, I need to include the headers. A sample of my csv file looks like:

```
 Time,Household 1,Household 2, .....  
 Timestamp,Vehicle 1,Vehicle 2,......  
 01-01-2010 00:00:00,0,0,....  
 01-01-2010 00:00:10,0,0,....  
 .                  ,.,....  
 .                  ,.,....  
 .                  ,.,....  
 .                  ,.,....
```

here is the code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


household = pd.read_csv(r'/home/deras/Desktop/PEV-Profiles-new.csv',index_col = False,dtype='unicode',delimiter = ',')
#print (household)
i = 1
k = 0
j = 0
for row in household:
    d1 = household.iloc[:,k]
    d2 = household.iloc[:,i]
    d3 = d1 + d2
    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1
    Path = '/home/deras/Desktop/csv_parsing_new/Load_Profile'+str(j)+'.csv'
    d3.to_csv(Path)
    j = j + 1
    if i == 348:# and k == 1:
        break
```

Any help would appreciate it.

Comment: *"What I want to do is to read the first ..."* but you are reading the whole csv. Do you mean what you want to do is *write* the lower triangle of the data?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a CSV file with N columns, and you want to slice it into N-1 individual CSV files with columns (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), ..., (1,N). If so, this should do it:

```py
col_first = household.columns[0]

for i in range(1, household.shape[1]):
    col_i = household.columns[i]
    household.loc[:, [col_first, col_i]].to_csv(f'{i}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary with slices of your dataframe.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

s = pd.Series(list(ascii_lowercase))

df = pd.get_dummies(s)

columns = [ [col1,col2] for col1,col2 in zip(df.columns.tolist()[::2], df.columns.tolist()[1::2] )]
```

---

```
print(columns)

[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l'], ['m', 'n'], ['o', 'p'], ['q', 'r'], ['s', 't'], ['u', 'v'], ['w', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]
```

---

```
slice_df_dict = {number : df[col] for number,col in enumerate(columns)}

print(slice_df_dict[5])

   k  l
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   0  0
3   0  0
4   0  0
5   0  0
6   0  0
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   0  0
10  1  0
11  0  1
12  0  0
13  0  0
14  0  0
15  0  0
16  0  0
17  0  0
18  0  0
19  0  0
20  0  0
21  0  0
22  0  0
23  0  0
24  0  0
25  0  0
```

if you need to write it to separate csv files.

```
[data.to_csv(f'{number}.csv',index=False) for number,data in slice_df_dict.items()]
```